# Compare datetime get different result

Tags: c#

I need to compare two dates including the seconds. I searched the web and got two methods. One is import `Microsoft.VisualBasic dll`. The result is not same when it runs the same data. I think C# should do the same thing without import VisualBasic. Can someone point the way to me to made it work in C#?

Thanks in advance.

There is one using Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
 if (Math.Abs(DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, 
     Conversions.ToDate(colFilesFound[RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(rw["file_path"])]),
     Conversions.ToDate(rw["last_modified_timestamp"]), 
     FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1)) == 0L)
 {
     unchangedFileNum++;
     Console.WriteLine("unchange");
 }
 else
 {
     modifiedFileNum++;
     Console.WriteLine("change");
 }
```

There is another method not using Visual.dll:

```
DateTime fileLastModifiedDate = Conversions.ToDate(colFilesFound[rw["file_path"]]);
DateTime dataLastModifiedDate = Conversions.ToDate(rw["last_modified_timestamp"]);
if (Math.Abs((fileLastModifiedDate - dataLastModifiedDate).TotalSeconds) == 0L)
{
     Console.WriteLine("File Date: " + colFilesFound[rw["file_path"]] + 
            " <> Database Date: " + Conversions.ToString(rw["last_modified_timestamp"]));
     unchangedFileNum++;
     Console.WriteLine("unchange");
}
else
{
     modifiedFileNum++;
     Console.WriteLine("change");
}
```

Comment: What is Conversions.ToDate? It doesn't help that you haven't given us any sample data, and your code uses other code unnecessarily. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `==` operator to test for equality?

Comment: Could you compare the `Ticks` or is that too granular?

Comment: You want to compare "including seconds."  Does that mean "excluding milliseconds"?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to compare DateTimes in .NET is using the == operator or calling the [DateTime.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) method:

```
    DateTime fileLastModifiedDate = ...;
    DateTime dataLastModifiedDate = ...;

    if (fileLastModifiedDate == dataLastModifiedDate)
    {
       ...
    }
```

You need to take into account the **precission**. Sometimes, you cannot have enough precission to consider **milliseconds**. In this case you need to compare the dates without having into account the milliseconds:

```
public static bool IsSameDateWithoutMilliseconds(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return d1.Subtract(d2).TotalSeconds == 0;
}
```

Comment: Ugly. Wouldn't `d1.Subtract(d2).TotalSeconds;` be simpler.

Comment: Why do you need `Math.Abs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the milliseconds since those are probably not equal the way you check the DateTimes.

```
DateTime fileLastModifiedDate = Conversions.ToDate(colFilesFound[rw["file_path"]]);
DateTime dataLastModifiedDate = Conversions.ToDate(rw["last_modified_timestamp"]);

fileLastModifiedDate = fileLastModifiedDate.AddMilliseconds(-fileLastModifiedDate.Millisecond);
dataLastModifiedDate = dataLastModifiedDate.AddMilliseconds(-dataLastModifiedDate.Millisecond);

if (DateTime.Compare(fileLastModifiedDate, dataLastModifiedDate) == 0)
{
    // dates are equal
}
else
{
    // dates are not equal
}
```